# Emberjs - Saving model with belongsTo from a modal

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a Todo record with a belongsTo relationship, Category, from a modal window and saving it.

Considering the following jsbin

http://jsbin.com/UlADutAj/1

In the modal window the todo has the category, you can see the title printed there, but once I save in the controller action, the category is not set.

It's done here with Fixtures, but I've got the same problem with ActiveModelSerializer.

If I use a normal route, not one with a modal, it works, so I'm guessing it's something wrong with my modal code, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a timing issue. You need to wait for your content to save (i.e. the promise to resolve) before closing the modal and performing a `rollback`.

You can check out this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aYOzEnEx/2/edit?html,js,console,output) which changes the following:

```
saveTodo: function() {
  var context = this;
  var todo;
  todo = this.get('model');

  todo.save().then(function () {
    // Now the save is complete and the isDirty flag is false. 
    context.send('closeModal');
  });
}
```